# programmatic appium in C#

Tags: c#, node.js, selenium, appium

I keep getting this error when trying to kick off Appium in C#:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumServiceBuilder.get_InstalledNodeInCurrentFileSystem()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumServiceBuilder.CheckAppiumJS()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumServiceBuilder.get_Args()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.AppiumServiceBuilder.Build()
   at FSI.Mobile.SD.Test.UI.Android.ServerTests.StartingAppLocallyTest.CheckThatServiseIsNotRunWhenTheCreatingOfANewSessionIsFailed() in C:\Users\jgooding\Source\Repos\FSI.Mobile.SD.Test\FSI.Mobile.SD.Test.UI.Android\ServerTests\StartingAppLocallyTest.cs:line 156
Result Message: OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Service.Exceptions.InvalidServerInstanceException : Invalid server instance exception has occurred: There is no installed nodes! Please install  node via NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html)
```

I've tried installing the appium node all over the place, but nothing seems to work.  Can someone tell me exactly where to put the node so that my code can find it?  I don't know the default location it's looking to find it.

node is installed and running (this is how I installed appium).

[node test from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGYEb.png)

Comment: `get_InstalledNodeInCurrentFileSystem` tells me Appium require node.js to be installed on your computer. Verify it is installed and that you can run node from your command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I re-installed nodejs into the default location (it was on my Desktop before), and then updated this line to reflect that change:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(AppiumServiceConstants.NodeBinaryPath, @"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe");
```

This seemed to fix the "no installed nodes" error.